# Options for `docker start` vs `docker run`

Tags: docker, reddit

I'm having a tough time conceptually with some Docker commands.  Let's suppose, not entirely hypothetically, that I'm building an image that needs `--privileged` for the build.  I can't figure out a way to do this.  Let's further suppose that I defer the step that needs the privilege until the first run- and then I forget to specify `--privileged` for that first run.  Now I have a container- and `docker start` won't let me specify `--privileged` either.  There are analogous problems with `docker start` for specifying, say, a shell when I forgot to do it in the Dockerfile or with `docker run`.  Is there a way to rectify these problems?

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.5

ENV TERM            linux
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV REDDIT_USER     reddit

RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install  -y aptitude
RUN aptitude update
RUN aptitude upgrade -o Aptitude::Delete-Unused=1 -y
RUN aptitude install -y vim-nox git screen zsh wget software-properties-common
RUN git clone https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" reddit

# can't run this in build; instead, start the image with --privileged and then run the script manually
#RUN echo "y" | ./reddit/install-reddit.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Some options (like `--privileged`) can only be specified when you create a container, but this isn't intended to be a heavy-weight process.  Why not delete the container with the wrong options and `docker run` a new one?

Comment: The issue is that the container isn't complete at the build phase- it has to be tweaked with `docker run --privileged`.  I guess what I'm asking is: is there a way to wait to "freeze" the image until after I'm done setting things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run as a privileged during builds, [unless you use buildx](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916#issuecomment-530278444). What you can do, however, is to make your changes on a container with `docker run --privileged`, then use [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) to turn it back into an image:

```
$ docker run -ti <image>
# do your thing...

$ docker commit <container id> final-image:version
```

Comment: aha, this was the incantation I was looking for!  Thank you.